# Why does the C++ compiler generate a temporary here?

Tags: c++

The following class is intended to monitor the changing state of another process; its constructor sets up const references to facilitate access to the relevant variables. Here's The ctor code:

```
template<typename FZYRSRC>
struct MergeableHeight: public FzyQty<FZYRSRC>
{
MergeableHeight( 
    const DDBuffer& me, const DDBuffer& neighbor, Orientation ori, bool useV =false)
: iP(me[PEAK_V].index()), iNP(neighbor[PEAK_V].index()),
  facingNeighbor(iP < iNP ? RIGHT_V : LEFT_V),  //vertex pointing to neighbor
  facingMe(iP < iNP ? LEFT_V : RIGHT_V),        //neighbor's vertex pointing to me
  iMyEdge(edgeBar(me,facingNeighbor)), iNeighborEdge(edgeBar(neighbor,facingMe)),
  myEdgeVal(me[facingNeighbor].datum()), neighborEdgeVal(neighbor[facingMe].datum()),
  myPeakVal(me[PEAK_V].datum()), useVolatility(useV),o(ori)             
{} 

 //member functions etc.
 private:
      virtual MergeableHeight* clone()const {return new MergeableHeight(*this);}
const int &iP, &iNP;
const PeakVertex facingNeighbor, facingMe; //PeakVertex is Enum {LEFT_V,PEAK_V,RIGHT_V} 
const int &iMyEdge, &iNeighborEdge;
const double &myEdgeVal, &neighborEdgeVal, &myPeakVal;
const Orientation o;
bool useVolatility;
  };
```

The class data members of interest are the two const int references iMyEdge and iNeighborEdge, initialized as

```
  iMyEdge(edgeBar(me,facingNeighbor)), iNeighborEdge(edgeBar(neighbor,facingMe)),
```

and the 3 const float references myEdgeVal, neighborEdgeVal, myPeakVal, initialized as

```
  myEdgeVal(me[facingNeighbor].datum()), 
  neighborEdgeVal(neighbor[facingMe].datum()),
  myPeakVal(me[PEAK_V].datum()),
```

In the former case (the ints) the references work as expected. In the floats case, the compiler gives the message

"warning C4413: 'MergeableHeight::myEdgeVal' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits," and similarly for the other two floats.

The user-defined DDBuffer type encapsulates a vector with a fixed number of DataDescriptors -- another user-defined type. DataDescriptor provides the member function datum(),

```
const float& datum()const {return _datum;}
```

while DDBuffer provides the [] operator,

```
const DatumDescriptor& operator[](int i)const {return buffer.at(i);}
DatumDescriptor& operator[](int i) {return buffer.at(i);} //const & non-const versions
```

Since everthing returns references, why on earth is a temporary being created here? In particular, the whole point is that the state variables should reflect the actual values in the references passed to the ctor, so I certainly wouldn't want a temporary created even if it was to remain in scope.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 10):

`datum()` returns a `const float&` and your variable is a `const double&`. You cannot convert one to the other, hence the temporary.

Comment: This is the simplest answer of all those posted, and apparently the correct one. Because of the difference in return types, a temporary must be created, just to have the right type to point to. A good reminder not to take these conversions for granted. I revised DataDescriptor to hold doubles, and the compiler is now happy. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

`myEdgeVal` is a reference to the data stored in `me` which is passed to the constructor.  As `me` is itself a const reference, it *could* be a temporary variable.  If it is, then `myEdgeVal` would be a reference to something inside an object that's destroyed after the constructor completes.

How do you construct the `MergeableHeight` object in your code?

Also, as all of those member int/double variables are constant, there is no need to make them references.

Comment: If they are references of non-temporaries, their value may be changed elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks for your input -- I think I've clarified your question in my response to the next posting -- see below.

Comment: The correct answer seems to be the first one that was posted -- by n.m.  See above. The gotcha's are often the really simplest things.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `me` is a ref-to-`const`, and so is the result of `me[facingNeighbor].datum()`.

However, the latter is a `const float&` and you're trying to bind it to a `const double&`, requiring a conversion. This produces a temporary, and it's one that exists only in the scope of the constructor.

Though its lifetime can be extended in higher stack frames (by binding to ref-to-`const`, as you know) it cannot magically be brought into lower stack frames.

---

Consider:

```
int foo();
const int& x = foo(); // valid; the result of foo() may exist as long as x does
```

But:

```
const int& foo() {
   return 5;          // not valid; returning reference to local variable
}

int x        = foo();
const int& y = foo(); // same issue.
                      // the `5` simply doesn't exist; its stack frame is gone.
```

Comment: MergeableHeight is part of an expression template library used to evaluate Fuzzy Expressions with continuously varying input data. MergeableHeight is one of several classes that serve as leaves in this Expression library -- they are the points where data enter the expression from the process being evaluated. These data are named state variables that are always in scope (below MergeableHeight in the stack), hence shouldn't be any problem due to temporaries there.

Comment: @IGottlieb: See my edited answer. Indeed, it's not the result of `datum` that goes out of scope, but the object to which it's converted.